# jQuery posting incorrectly serialized array of arrays

Tags: jquery, post, serialization, request

I am posting a data object containing an array of arrays that is currently

```
categorization: [['test']]
```

When I post this with jquery's `$.ajax()` the result is not correctly parsed by the server. Checking the request going out, the form data for this is passed as

```
categorization[0][]=test
```

If I alter the request to instead pass

```
categorization[0][0]=test
```

Then the value is correctly parsed by the server. My question is A) which one of these is correct and B) is there a way to direct jquery to serialize the array of arrays as the bottom example?

Comment: what does your ajax request look like?

Comment: i lost the request a few hours ago but I was passing the categorization array into an object called `data` and using that as the data value of the ajax call. I also was using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type. all other types I had passed in were parsed properly, it was only the array of arrays that had problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to take the JSON data object I'd been using and pass it to `JSON.stringify()`, then pass the resulting string as data and set the content type to json like so

```
var data = {
    categorization: [['test']]
}

$.ajax({
    url: "",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

This resulted in `categorization` being successfully cast to a `List<List<String>>`